# Composite key is blank and constraint fails on inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Having an error when inserting my data into this code into my database. I wanted to make the EventStaff have a primary key made up from StaffID.EventID like in this diagram at the bottom. I can't see to see what I'm doing wrong because the table in StaffID is populated and in TypeID. I was trying to create a composite key of two different tables, is this the wrong way to go about it> i've used the diagram reference.

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`EventStaff`, CONSTRAINT `fStaff1` FOREIGN KEY (`StaffID`) REFERENCES `Staff` (`StaffID`))
```

And this is the code for the database

```
CREATE TABLE  EventType (
TypeID INT NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR(200) NULL,
CONSTRAINT pEventType PRIMARY KEY (TypeID)
);
CREATE TABLE  Staff (
StaffID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pStaff PRIMARY KEY (StaffID)
);

CREATE TABLE  Event (
EventID INT NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR(500) NULL,
Name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
DateStart DATE NULL,
DateEnd DATE NULL,
TimeStart TIME NULL,
TimeEnd TIME NULL,
TypeID INT NULL,
ClientID INT NULL,
NoBands BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
MaxFoodStall INT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pEvent PRIMARY KEY (EventID),
CONSTRAINT fType1 FOREIGN KEY (TypeID) REFERENCES  EventType (TypeID),
);

CREATE TABLE  EventStaff (
StaffID int NOT NULL,
EventID int NOT NULL,
Role VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, EventID),
CONSTRAINT fStaff1 FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES  Staff (StaffID),
CONSTRAINT FEvent1 FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES  Event (EventID)
);
```

and here are the inserts

```
insert into EventType (TypeID, Description) values (1, 'Intuitive attitude-oriented hierarchy');
insert into EventType (TypeID, Description) values (2, 'Mandatory executive concept');

insert into Staff (StaffID) values (1);
insert into Staff (StaffID) values (2);

 insert into Event (EventID, Description , DateStart, DateEnd, TimeStart, TimeEnd, NoBands, MaxFoodStall, Name) values (1, 'Cloned 6th generation pricing structure', '2018-03-13', '2018-07-20', '11:18 PM', '4:58 PM', false, 17, 'Swaniawski-Ankunding');
insert into Event (EventID, Description , DateStart, DateEnd, TimeStart, TimeEnd, NoBands, MaxFoodStall, Name) values (2, 'Ameliorated mission-critical throughput', '2017-10-11', '2019-01-05', '10:44 AM', '8:26 PM', true, 4, 'Langworth-Ferry');

  insert into EventStaff (Role) values ('Editor');
 insert into EventStaff (Role) values ('Budget/Accounting Analyst IV');
```

https://image.ibb.co/jwaxRx/problem.png

Comment: You still need to set the StaffID and EventID values when inserting EventStaff records.  Then, if you happen to insert ID's that aren't in your reference tables, you will receive a failure.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted to this question has typos, and won't even run as is.  Once I fixed those, I was able to reproduce your foreign key error.  The problem is actually being caused by these last two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO EventStaff (Role) VALUES ('Editor');
INSERT INTO EventStaff (Role) VALUES ('Budget/Accounting Analyst IV');
```

You are not specifying values for the `StaffID` and `EventID`, and these columns have been marked as not nullable.  They are foreign keys, and it would actually have been OK to insert `NULL`, had you not marked the columns as non nullable.  Here is one way to make this error go away:

```
INSERT INTO EventStaff (Role, StaffID, EventID)
    VALUES ('Editor', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO EventStaff (Role, StaffID, EventID)
    VALUES ('Budget/Accounting Analyst IV', 2, 2);
```

I don't know what values you intend to insert, but the above is one way to go here.

Note that in your insets into the `Event` table, you *don't* specify a value for the `TypeID` column, which is also a foreign key.  However, in this case, you have marked the column as nullable, so MySQL accepts it.